# WordPress : Add a link to a custom post type's page from the WYSIWYG editor

Tags: wordpress, wysiwyg, custom-post-type

I have a custom post type in WordPress. I would like to be able to create a link to it from the WYSIWYG editor. When creating a link, my custom post type does not appear under Add a link to content from your website.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

A custom post type will not show as a page link because you have not created a page for the CPT.

Your custom post type url would be http://website.com/?post_type

Comment: I understand it is not a page per se, but it does have its own URL. I am trying to link to this URL from WP's content editor (WYSIWYG). I went back in some previous projects I've worked on and CPTs often show up under additional content when creating a link from the content editor. I just can't seem to find documentation on why they are not showing right now.

Comment: If you have created and published a custom post then it should show up in your list of pages. My apologies, I thought you were requesting a link to the CPT archive link.

Comment: No problem! And yes, I have created multiple posts, but they are not, which I find rather weird.. It seems its a given that CPTs should show up there, and I can't find documentation as to why they do not.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. I use Polylang also, but my CPT is language-independent. If I set them to a language, then they appear in the link-search.